# Foundation 6 Sites - Dropdown: Pane Doesn't Open on Click

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I'm having an issue toggling the dropdown pane. When data-hover is set to true, the following code works as expected and as shown in the documentation, however removing data-hover or setting it to false so that the button needs to be clicked to reveal the content does not work. The content is never revealed (on click, the "is-open" class is not being toggled).

This is happening whether the data-auto-focus="true" attribute (as shown in the docs) is set or not.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance for your time.

```
<button id="_admin-menu" data-toggle="_admin-content">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
</button>

<div id="_admin-content" class="dropdown-pane" data-hover="false">
    <ul class="no-bullet text-center">
        LINKS
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `data-dropdown`

```
<button id="_admin-menu" data-toggle="_admin-content">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
</button>

<div id="_admin-content" class="dropdown-pane" data-dropdown data-hover="false">
    <ul class="no-bullet text-center">
        LINKS
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, missed that entering the code in here. With the data-dropdown attribute it still doesn't work.

Even if I copy and paste in the code directly from the docs, the dropdown toggle isn't working.

Comment: Make sure you have all the required files loaded and foundation initialized. I tested the answer, it will work if foundation is set up correctly.

Comment: There was an issue in my setup, one of those so-simple-that-you-miss-it-entirely kind of things. Thanks for your help and your time.